# Rails redirect issue with HTTPS because of symlink

Tags: redirect, ruby-on-rails-3.1, https

This is a little different than all the other Rails 3 redirect https questions out there. Let me explain.

In order to publish our site with Phusion Passenger we had to create a subdomain and use a symlink (or softlink or alias) from the `www/rails` folder to `/home/user/app/railsapp`.

In order for the HTTPS to work (because of various domains issues) we need to have a rewrite mod that actually creates this route:

```
https://my.site.com/rails
```

Notice the trailing **/rails** route.

This route does not exist on our app. So what I need is a way to redirect anything that comes in with that route to:

```
https://my.site.com/login
```

So I thought I'd do this, in the `routes.rb` file have this:

```
match '/rails' => 'sessions#redirect_to_login'
```

In sessions_controllers.rb:

```
  def redirect_to_login
    redirect_to login_path, :status => :moved_permanently
  end
```

This results in the app complaining that it can't find `/rais/login/` so it's still seeking that `/rails` bit.

If I add something like `redirect_to "/"` which in turn will send you to `my.site.com/login` with a redirect when you're not logged in, I'll get an error of too many redirects in the browser.

`redirect_to login_url` didn't do the trick either.

It gets a bit more complicated in the sense that whenever I'm using the https protocol for that site, it will append that `/rails` route so I need a way to remove it from all the links. For example, `https://my.site.com/movies` will get translated to `https://my.site.com/rails/movies`.

Either remove the `/rails` or redirect all https traffic to http except for the login page.

I'm sure there is a relatively easy fix for this, but I can't figure it out.

Help is appreciated.